# Slide effect is not smooth

Tags: c#, winforms, animation

I am trying to move a control to another control's position in a sliding effect. The below code works but it is not smooth as expected. I know repaint has to happen for every one pixel move and that has all things to do with this problem. Is there anything I can do to make it smooth?

```
void changePage(Control currentPage, Control newPage)
{
    int curPageStartX = currentPage.Location.X;
    newPage.Location = new Point(currentPage.Size.Width + curPageStartX, currentPage.Location.Y);
    while (newPage.Location.X > curPageStartX)
    {
        currentPage.Location = new Point(currentPage.Location.X - 1, currentPage.Location.Y);
        newPage.Location = new Point(newPage.Location.X - 1, newPage.Location.Y);
    }
}
```